# Error:[Brasero Disk Burner]: You do not have the required permissions to use this drive

Tags: permissions, brasero

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 and then installed some programs. Now, When I run the "Brasero Disk Burner" for  creating an image from a DVD, It gives me an error:

> The image could not be created at the specified location. Do you want to
>   specify another location for this session or retry with the current
>   location?
>
> You do not have the required permissions to use this drive.

I checked the permissions for my home directory and it shows nothing wrong:

> Folder access: Create and delete files

I tried to create the image on different folders in vain. I wonder what the problem is?

Comment: Start Brasero via the terminal and see if there are any other errors. Also check /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1):

Problem self solved

> I just noticed that I am able to put the image in the "Documents" folder.